# Changing upload directory for plugin uploads only

Tags: plugin-development, uploads

I've spent a lot of time reading the other threads on this question, but I just cannot get my code to function properly.

I'm building a plugin, and I've set up an upload form on my custom admin page, and I am using Media Uploader to process the upload.  Please see below for simplified code:

```
class myPlugin() {
  function __construct(){
    add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', array( $this, 'handle_upload_prefilter') );
    add_filter('wp_handle_upload', array( $this, 'handle_upload') );
  }

  function handle_upload_prefilter( $file ) {
    add_filter('upload_dir', array( $this, 'custom_upload_dir' ) );
    return $file;
  }

  function handle_upload( $fileinfo )   {
    remove_filter('upload_dir', array( $this, 'custom_upload_dir' ) );
    return $fileinfo;
  }

  function custom_upload_dir($args) {   
    $args['path'] = $args['basedir'] . "/mypath" . $args['subdir'];
    $args['url'] = $args['baseurl'] . "/mypath" . $args['subdir'];
    return $args;
  }
}
```

The code above works, and it changes the upload directory to the path that I specify.  However, it is changing the upload directory for ALL uploads.  I'd like my code to run only when uploading from my custom admin page.

This is what I've tried so far (and has not worked for me):

1. I've tried using conditionals to test for `$pagenow` and `get_current_screen` in my `custom_upload_dir` function, but that seems to fail every time and uses the default upload paths.
2. I've tried testing for conditional in my `__construct` but I get returned an error (I guess it's too early in the WP lifecycle).
3. Tried running the conditional in my `handle_upload_prefilter` function also to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be something identifiable about your form data, such as your input names. Check for one or more of those and process accordingly.

```
function custom_upload_dir($args) {   
    if (isset($_POST['something'])) {
        $args['path'] = $args['basedir'] . "/mypath" . $args['subdir'];
        $args['url'] = $args['baseurl'] . "/mypath" . $args['subdir'];
    }
    return $args;
}
```

After some investigation, the only things I see that might help are ...

1. The post ID is passed through the `POST` data to the callback.
   However I don't know this would be set to in you custom plugin page.
2. `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` appears to be set correctly. You could
   parse that to determine if your plugin page is the originating 
   page.

If I had the full plugin source I could do some testing.

Comment: Wouldn't this only work once the form has been submitted?

Perhaps I should have clarified in my original question that I'm using the Media Uploader (I'll go ahead and edit my post to include this information). Unless my understanding of the process is incorrect, since I won't have actually submitted my form, I can't check to see if an input is set, correct?

Comment: Also, in my `custom_upload_dir` function, I tried to test for `$_GET['page'] == 'my_page_name'` but that did not work either

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @s_ha_dum with your $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] suggestion i have a workable solution. Only thing i had to hardcopy the =="urlfrommyplugin"

Comment: If you expect that URL to change, save it to the database-- `$wpdb->options` seems like a fit.

Comment: I will try a combination of your suggestions, there's some really good insight there, thank you.

I partially inherited the project from a previous employee so while I kind of extend the functionality, I'm also reworking the structure of it.

If I can get it to a readable, coherent state in the near future, I will post the source code and if you have some time, perhaps you could look through it :)

But thank you for the help you've provided already!

Comment: There is a [codereview.se] site that may be a better fit for that kind of "how does my code look" question. Just let me know if you post it (put @s_ha_dum in a comment)